# Haskell - types and if statements

Tags: if-statement, haskell, types, polymorphism

Is there a good way to use type information to choose to do different things?

For example, this isn't valid Haskell, but I don't see why it couldn't be:

```
tostring :: (Show b) => b -> String
tostring x = f x where f = if b == String then tail . init . show else show
```

The important part is not getting the correct string out, but using the type of `b` as a way to switch between functionality/functions.

Comment: Haskell doesn't preserve types during runtime (by default). In many cases, that's a bad idea and a big detriment to performance. However, your usecase is precisely what ad hoc polymorphism is for: use a typeclass to switch!

Comment: there are ways to have runtime type checking in Haskell (`Data.Typeable`) - but there's no reason to do that.

Comment: you could also simply have `data Foo a = FooStr String | FooOther a` and use it like `tostring :: Show a => Foo a -> String` - pattern match on constructor

Comment: @Chase
If I do as your last comment states, then how do I choose between the FooStr constructor and the FooOther constructor? And how exactly would I use a typeclass to do this? My problem is not that the information doesn't exist, but the Haskell space is so noisy I can't find anything with the keywords I know.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the last statement. You choose between the constructors via [pattern matching](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching).

Comment: `newtype MyString = MyString String`, `instance Show MyString where show (MyString x) = ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@chi's answer already demonstrates how to use `Typeable` to do run-time type checking, but I'd like to point out that to me, this looks like exactly the thing typeclasses are meant for. For your example, the only problem is that you don't like the `Show` implementation for `String`: In that case, just create your own typeclass!

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

-- The class
class MyShow a where
    myShow :: a -> String

-- The instance for String
-- (The `OVERLAPPING` pragma is required, because
-- otherwise GHC won't know which instance to choose for String)
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} MyShow [Char] where
    myShow = tail . init . show

-- For everything that is not a String, just copy the Show instance
instance Show a => MyShow a where
    myShow = show
```

EDIT: As pointed out by leftaroundabout, overlapping instances are complicated and can lead to some unexpected behavior. Look at the [example](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap) at the bottom of the documentation.

Comment: A remark is on order on how overlapping instances are kind of against the grain of Haskell's typeclass mechanism, and often lead to problems. It may be preferrable to manually add instances for exactly those types where it makes sense.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I've added a note, thanks. I don't think I have enough knowledge to suggest an alternative in this particular case (and I'm not sure it's really needed) so please let me know if you have any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

I will answer the question as it is. Haskell erases all type information during compile time, mostly for efficiency reasons. By default, when a polymorphic function is called, e.g. `f :: a->a`, no type information is available, and `f` has no way to know what `a` actually is -- in this case, `f` can only be the identity function, fail to terminate, or raise an error.

For the rare cases where type information is needed, there is `Typeable`. A polymorphic function having type `f :: Typeable a => ...` is passed a run-time description of the type `a`, allowing it to test it. Essentially, the `Typeable a` constraint forces Haskell to keep the runtime information until run time. Note that such type information must be known at the call site -- either because `f` is called with a completely known type, or because `f` is called with a partially known type (say `f x` with `x :: Maybe b`) but there are suitable `Typeable` constraints in scope (`Typeable b`, in the previous example).

Anyway, here's an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables, GADTs #-}

import Data.Typeable

tostring :: forall b. (Show b, Typeable b) => b -> String
tostring x = case eqT @b @String of  -- if b==String
   Just Refl -> x                    -- then
   Nothing   -> show x               -- else
```

Note how we were able to return `x` in the "then" branch, since there it is known to be a `String`.

Comment: A simpler implementation is `toString x = case cast x of {Nothing -> show x; Just x' -> x'}`. No type applications required.

Comment: @leftaroundabout In this specific case `cast` is indeed the best approach. Above I showed the `eqT` approach since that allows one to test "`b==String`" in the general case.